# Calculate integral given the area of the domain

Tags: integration

How do I find the area of the following domain: $ D= \{(x,y)|\ 2x^2+y^2 \leq1, \ y<0\}$ . I found that the value of $x$ should be $\pm \sqrt2/2 $ but how can I integrate? I don't understand this type of problem because I don't know what I have to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$2x^2+y^2=1$ is an ellipse (can you sketch it ?). For $y>0$ we have $y=\sqrt{1-2x^2}$. Can you find the area between this function and the $x$ axis?

Comment: or you can use half of area $\tfrac{\pi ab}{2}$

Comment: Im not really sure how to sketch that but why do I use half of area?

Comment: Because for $y>0$ we have half of the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple change of coordinates, your region can become the bottom half of the unit disk.

Here's how: let $u=\sqrt2 x$ and $v=y$, so
$dxdy=\frac{dudv}{\sqrt2}$

Applying this transformation to $D$ yields: $2x^2+y^2\leq1\rightarrow u^2+v^2\leq1$ and $y\leq0\rightarrow v\leq0$

The region in $uv$ space is now the bottom half of the unit disk, which I shall name $U$.

So: $\iint_D dxdy = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\iint_U dudv$